# How to inner join for the resultted query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an mysql query for getting which user assigned to which course and if the course having certificate then only the results will be prints. for this i am using inner join with many  table. Here is the code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.fullname,usr.id, usr.username, usr.email, c.enrolenddate 
FROM m_tl_course AS c 
INNER JOIN m_tl_context AS cx ON c.id = cx.instanceid AND cx.contextlevel = '50' 
INNER JOIN m_tl_role_assignments AS ra ON cx.id = ra.contextid 
INNER JOIN m_tl_role AS r ON ra.roleid = r.id 
INNER JOIN m_tl_user AS usr ON ra.userid = usr.id 
INNER JOIN m_tl_certificate AS ce ON ce.course = c.id 
WHERE r.name = "Student" and ra.timeend = '0'
```

I have an another table to having data's like the user's who's download their certificate. The table name is m_tl_certification.

In this table having Columns like, user_id ( this the user id), Course_id  (this is the course id), cert_date ( this is the certificate download date).

What i want is i want to get the user's who is not download their certicate.

How to get this. please can anyone help me ?

Comment: like the second concept not in the first concept ?

Comment: Can you try replacing `where r.name = 'Student' and ra.timeend = '0'` with `LEFT JOIN m_tl_certification cert on usr.id = cert.user_id and c.id = cert.course_id
WHERE r.name = 'Student' and ra.timeend = '0' and cert.cert_date is null`?

Comment: voted to close as unclear

Comment: sorry if i do this means its return the all records only

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: One of the query patterns that will work is called an "anti-join".  For example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366021/checking-whether-an-item-does-not-exist-in-another-table/9366094#9366094.  As another option, you could use a `NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery)` predicate.

Comment: how to use not exists with my above query can you please modify my query

Comment: @Nisanth accept an answer, so it can help other users

Answer (score 0):

What will be the column value if not downloaded and if downloaded. If the Download date is NULL then in where add Download_Date IS NULL

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.fullname,usr.id, usr.username, usr.email,c.enrolenddate 
 FROM m_tl_course AS c                                            
 INNER JOIN m_tl_context AS cx ON c.id = cx.instanceid AND cx.contextlevel = '50' 
 INNER JOIN m_tl_role_assignments AS ra ON cx.id = ra.contextid      
 INNER JOIN m_tl_role AS r ON ra.roleid = r.id 
 INNER JOIN m_tl_user AS usr ON ra.userid = usr.id 
 INNER JOIN m_tl_certificate AS ce ON ce.course = c.id INNER JOIN m_tl_certificate AS ce ON ce.course = c.id 
 INNER JOIN m_tl_certification As cee ON cee.user_id = usr.id
 WHERE r.name = "Student" and ra.timeend = '0' and cee.downloadDate IS NULL
```

Comment: no actually if the user download their certificate means then only the m_tl_certification table having entry, otherwisethis table not having entry

Comment: sounds good then use inner join for m_tl_certification don't put the where condition for cee.downloadDate (which is not required) in first line .i.e                 SELECT DISTINCT c.fullname,usr.id, usr.username, usr.email,c.enrolenddate <here > add any column of m_tl_certification table. which will return empty so after generating result compare if  any column of m_tl_certification table is empty then it is not downloaded.

Comment: .i.e for the query which you sent inner join m_tl_certification and get details of certification table if no rows found then it is not downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query with the following

```
  SELECT DISTINCT c.fullname,usr.id, usr.username, usr.email, c.enrolenddate 
  FROM m_tl_course AS c 
  INNER JOIN m_tl_context AS cx ON c.id = cx.instanceid AND cx.contextlevel = '50' 
  INNER JOIN m_tl_role_assignments AS ra ON cx.id = ra.contextid 
  INNER JOIN m_tl_role AS r ON ra.roleid = r.id 
  INNER JOIN m_tl_user AS usr ON ra.userid = usr.id 
  LEFT JOIN m_tl_certificate AS ce ON ce.course = c.id 
  WHERE r.name = "Student" and ra.timeend = '0'
```